# fixed not fullsize header in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

iam trying to set my header fixed. but it only works with fullsize...i cant find my fault.
my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/3234/

if i use `<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" >` its not fixed but with the width i want, if i use   `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" >`  its from the left border to the right border of my browser, like facebook. how can i get that fixed with the size of the sidebar+content? thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
.footer-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 925px;
    margin: auto 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Maybe you can use `margin` and `width` for the header too. You know your code, so you probably find a proper class for those.

Comment: i tried it, but then i dont have it centered like the sidebar and content.

Comment: @user1010775 I've edited my `footer` code. It seems I didn't read your question properly. In the fiddle there is the text "Should be over complete width" in the footer, and I just rushed to fix that... :).

Comment: yeah i tought so ;). but the header is my problem. if i try it like this i loose my dynamic width...cant find a better solution